# Has Sri Ramakrishna reincarnated?

Tags: rebirth, ramakrishna

Sri Ramakrishna said that he will be born again after 100 years*. He died in 1886. So if he kept his promise, he is with us again! Now, he should be 35 years old.

Does anybody know his whereabouts? Did Ramakrishna Mission try to find the reborn saint?

There is a tradition among Tibetan Buddhists where the Sangha actively looks for the newly reincarnated Dalai Lama. Does something similar happen here?

*References:

1. [They Lived with God: Life Stories of Some Devotees of Sri Ramakrishna by Swami Chetananda](https://www.amazon.in/They-Lived-God-Devotees-Ramakrishna/dp/8185301026/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=They%20lived%20with%20God&qid=1619238657&sr=8-1)
2. [How to Live with God: In the Company of Ramakrishna by Swami Chetananda](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0916356868)
3. [If Ramakrishna were alive today by Swami Chetananda in Vedanta Magazine Sep-Oct 2006 Issue published by Vedanta Centre UK](https://www.vedantauk.org/Magazine/2006/Sep-Oct2006.pdf)

Comment: where is the source that he said that he will be born after 100 years?

Comment: Ramakrishna did say that he would have to take one more birth in the North West direction from Dakshineswar. How can any of us know if that has happened?

Comment: The reference to His returning is in the Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, chapter 44 where he says it will be in a Northwesterly direction from Dakshineswar. I have a vague memory of reading somewhere else that He made another reference that it would be withing the next few hundred years (of the 1880s), but I have been unable to find the reference..

Comment: Sri Ramakrishna is Avatara not saint. A saint cannot claim to reborn again on this earth, for birth and death are in God's hand. Only Avatara can say that he will reborn again, as Krishna has said in the Gita. In Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Ramakrishna is quoted as saying: "I shall have to assume a human body again, in a northwesterly direction." In the book How to live with God it is mentioned on pg-486 - Swami Vivekananda says to Mrs. Alice Hansbrough : "The Master said he would come again in about two hundred years - and I will come with him. When a Master comes, he brings his own people."